# How to parse data from php in jQuery if received Array & Object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parsing, echo

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//Some code
$files_arr['BadIMG'][$i] = $fileName;
//Some code
$files_arr['GoodIMG'][$i] = $path;
//Some code
echo json_encode($files_arr);
```

JS:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.BadIMG);
    console.log(response.GoodIMG);
    for (var i = 0; i < response.GoodIMG.length; i++) {
        var src = response.GoodIMG[i];
        $('#fast-reply_textarea').focus().val($('#fast-reply_textarea').val() + '\n[img]https://url/' + src + '[/img]\n');
    }
}
```

If from PHP received only **GoodIMG**, all it`t ok and in **#fast-reply_textarea** successfully added links for images:

```
console.log(response.BadIMG);
undefined
console.log(response.GoodIMG);
Array [ "1_Good.jpg", "2_Good.jpg" ]
```

But if from PHP received **GoodIMG** + **BadIMG** nothing inserted in **#fast-reply_textarea**:

```
console.log(response.BadIMG);
Array [ "1_Bad.jpg", "2_Bad.jpg" ]

console.log(response.GoodIMG);
Object { 2: "1_Good.jpg", 3: "2_Good.jpg" }
```

And if from PHP received onlly **BadIMG**:

```
console.log(response.BadIMG);
Array [ "1_Bad.jpg", "2_Bad.jpg" ]

console.log(response.GoodIMG);
undefined //With error:
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "length", response.GoodIMG is undefined
```

How to parse this data if received **BadIMG** together with **GoodIMG** and add **GoodIMG** links in editor?
For **BadIMG** I will add alert, like as: From (Count all images) images (Count or Names of BadIMG) not uploaded.

Comment: I think the creation of `$files_arr['GoodIMG']` is under conditions. Add it in every case or check if it is defined in JS `if (response.GoodIMG) { for (...)`.

Comment: But if received GoodIMG together with BadIMG?

Comment: Why not return the same structure in all cases to avoid such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `$i` index in your arrays in PHP.

```
$files_arr['BadIMG'][] = $fileName;
$files_arr['GoodIMG'][] = $path;
```

In this case, both will be arrays, not objects.

Also, in JS, you should test if the variables are defined or not.

```
success: function(response) {
    if (typeof response.GoodIMG !== "undefined") {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.GoodIMG.length; i++) {
            var src = response.GoodIMG[i];
            $('#fast-reply_textarea').focus().val($('#fast-reply_textarea').val() + '\n[img]https://url/' + src + '[/img]\n');
        }
    }
}
```